# How to generate highly uniform random number in python?

Tags: python, random, uniform

In somehow I need an random function that can generate highly uniform numbers, such as, when I say [5,5], and I run this function for 10 times, I would like to have 5 number that are less than 0.5 and other 5 numbers are greater than 0.5.

Every run should be separated, like:

```
for i in range(0,10):
   rnd=random_function([6,3,1])
   print rnd
```

After having run this function for ten times, then I have 6 numbers are less than 0.6, 3 numbers are between 0.6 and 0.9, and 1 number are between 0.9 to 1.

Does anyone know how can I do that? Because the random function inside python is not that uniform.... Thanks!!

Comment: Even the best RNGs won't always give you what you want. If you want numbers from some given range, then call the RNG with that range. Uniform distribution is something that happens as the number of numbers generated approaches infinity. Expecting uniformity in 10 random numbers is something you can't always count on.

Comment: This would be uniform only in the limit; if it were always uniform, that wouldn't be random, would it?

Comment: You should explain better what you're trying to do. If you want uniformity, you don't really want randomness. Use random functions where you really don't mind about the result, provided a range. In the first example you want two group of different random numbers.

Comment: A _uniform random number_ generator would be expected to have _all_ 10 numbers below 0.5 once in every 1024 trials. What you are asking for is something other than random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is *not* random; indeed, it is fairly structured. The point of random data is that it isn't structured: you can't say anything about what the values will be, only what they will be *on average*.

You can still do what you want, though: just specify the ranges you want your numbers to fall into.

```
>>> def random_function(*args):
...     n = sum(args)
...     bottom = 0
...     for m in args:
...             for _ in range(m):
...                     yield random.uniform(bottom, bottom + m/n)
...             bottom += m/n
...
>>> list(random_function(6,3,1))
[0.1849778317803791, 0.2779140519434712, 0.08380168147928498, 0.5477412922676888
, 0.5158697440011519, 0.5535466918038039, 0.8046993690361345, 0.714614514522802,
 0.7102988180048052, 0.9608096335125095]
>>> list(random_function(6,3,1))
[0.29313403848522546, 0.5543469551407342, 0.14208842652528347, 0.344464024804118
7, 0.3168266508239002, 0.5956620829410604, 0.673021479097414, 0.7141779120687652
, 0.7783099010964684, 0.9103924993423906]
```

---

Explanation:

Given `(6,3,1)`, work out their sum (`10`). We want six numbers between 0 and 6/10, three numbers between 6/10 and 6/10 + 3/10, and one number between 6/10 + 3/10 and 6/10 + 3/10 + 1/10. We can generate these by calling

```
random.uniform(0, 6/10) six times,
random.uniform(6/10, 9/10) three times, and
random.uniform(9/10, 1) once.
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it the essense of random that it's not uniform? If you want to generate 6 random numbers and you want half of them to be under 0.5 and the other half to be over 0.5, you should generate 3 numbers between 0 and 0.5 and generate 3 between 0.5 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's kind of defeating the purpose of "random" numbers, but Python does support this.

As part of the `random` module (`import random`), you can use `random.uniform(a,b)` instead of `random.random()` where `a` to `b` is the range in floating point.

More info in [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I've tried, but seems like the random.uniform(a,b) doesn't have much difference than the random.random()... :(

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know the context of your question, but it appears that what you may be looking for are [low-discrepancy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence)s rather than the usual pseudo-random numbers.

More specifically, check if Halton sequence gives you desired results. Python implementation [is available](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghalton).